# Electric charge operator and the charges of $W^\pm$ mesons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

In Ch.20 of the textbook *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by Peskin and Schroeder, when discussing spontaneous symmetry breaking in SU(2)$\times$U(1) in the context of Glashow-Weinberg-Salam theory on P.702, the electric charge is defined by

$$Q=T^3+Y\tag{20.69}$$

I understand the following. A global symmetry leads to a conserved current, whose zeroth component gives rise to a charge. In the case of SU(2), if the symmetry is not broken, there are three conserved currents. For Fermions, which furnish a fundamental representation of SU(2), they are $j^{\mu a}=\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\mu \tau^a\Psi$ with $a=1, 2, 3$ where projection onto chiral state is implied (the factors $\frac{1\pm \gamma^5}{2}$ or subscripts $\Psi_{L, R}$ are not really relevant here and therefore omitted for simplicity), $\tau^a$ are the matrices of the fundamental (spinor) representation of SU(2).

But since SU(2) is spontaneously broken, the vacuum does not necessarily remain unchanged under SU(2) rotation. In particular, for our specific choice, the vacuum is still invariant under the generator $T^3$ but transforms and generates the Goldstone bosons under $T^{1,2}$. Therefore, in the definition of $Q$, $T^3$ together with $Y$, are chosen and identified to be the electric charge.

If the above arguments are correct. I wanted to confirm that the electric charges of $W_\mu^\pm$ mesons, defined earlier, are truely $\pm 1$

$$W_\mu^\pm=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(A_\mu^1\mp iA_\mu^2)\tag{20.63}$$

by using (20.69).
It suffices to evaluate $T^3 W_\mu^\pm$, because $A_\mu^i$ with $(i={1,2,3})$ furnish a vector (adjoint) representation of SU(2) and are invariant under U(1).
By making use of the definition of matrix representation, namely,

$$T^3 A_\mu^i=A_\mu^j D(T^3)_{ji}, $$

and the explicit form of the matrix representation of the generator $T^3$

$$D(T^3)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i & 0\\ 
i & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is readily to verify that $T^3 A_\mu^1=-iA_\mu^2, T^3 A_\mu^2=-A_\mu^1$ and subsequently

$$QW_\mu^\pm= T^3 W_\mu^\pm=\mp W_\mu^\pm .$$

Apparently, I have missed a $(-1)$ sign, what have I missed?

Many thanks in advance for the explanation!

Comment: Why $T^3 A_\mu^i=A_\mu^j D(T^3)_{ji} $ and not $T^3 A_\mu^i= D(T^3)_{ij}A_\mu^j  $?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As I understand, this is a standard definition, see for instance, (3.1-2) on P.28 of "Group theory in physics", by Wu-Ki Tung. @Oбжорoв

Comment: I would be surprised if P&S have the same convention. After all, a representation is $D(T^a) D(T^b)$.

Comment: I actually did not know. All of the textbooks on group theory (in physics) I read have used the above convention. That is why I always thought it is the standard. I tried to google "matrix representation" but it does not give me the information on this convention. And indeed, the defintion you provided gives the correct sigh for the charge and by definition it is a presentation in terms of matrix.

Comment: @Oбжорoв  Would you please point to me a textbook, where the matrix representation is explicitly defined in terms of the bases, and the multiplication is applied from the right-hand side? Thanks!

Comment: P&S Section 15.4 should have this.

Comment: @Oбжорoв  Please let me know if I am wrong, I think there they talked about matrices satisfying multiplication rules of the group. So it seems that both conventions work alright.

Comment: It is just a convention. But you need to make sure you use it consistently throughout.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that with care. Great QFT notes by the way, will read them soon and send you my feedback :D